# Python for loops overwriting previous iteration

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy array of periodic squares such that when I use plt.imshow I will see a black square with periodic white squares. The array needs to be used later on for Fourier analysis. The imshow reference is just for visualisation of the problem.

I can create the black array and a single white square, but the issue I'm having is that every iteration is overwriting the last until I am left with only the last white square.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 500
x_wid = 10
y_wid = 10

grid = np.arange(1,N)
X_GRID, Y_GRID = np.meshgrid(grid, grid)

square = np.zeros([N, N])

for x_pos in np.arange(0, N, N/10):
    for y_pos in np.arange(0, N, N/10):
        square = np.logical_and((np.abs(X_GRID-x_pos) < x_wid/2),
            (np.abs(Y_GRID-y_pos) < y_wid/2))

plt.imshow(square, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your problem isn't that `square` is being overwritten, it's that you only plot the final value. Some sort of plot command needs to go in the loop

Comment: by periodic white squares, do you mean a checkerboard pattern?

Comment: You need to collect the `square` values for all iterations - in some sort of structure.  As it is `square` is just the value derived for one `x, y` pair.  You know how to iterate and collect values in a list, don't you?  or list of lists?

Comment: @BallpointBen Sorry I should have mentioned, and will edit, that I need the final array not just for plotting but also for further manipulation down the track.

Comment: @hpaulj No I do not know how to iterate and collect values

Answer (score 0):

The size of the original grid needs to be N so `grid = np.arange(0,N)`. This will then have the same size as `square` allowing for a simple `+=` in the for loop to 'append' with every iteration.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 500
x_wid = 10
y_wid = 10

grid = np.arange(0,N)
X_GRID, Y_GRID = np.meshgrid(grid, grid)

square = np.zeros([N, N])
final_square = np.zeros([N, N])

for x_pos in np.arange(0, N, N/10):
    for y_pos in np.arange(0, N, N/10):
        square = np.logical_and((np.abs(X_GRID-x_pos) < x_wid/2),
            (np.abs(Y_GRID-y_pos) < y_wid/2))
        final_square += square

plt.imshow(final_square, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```